# Logo - Updating with new logo

Tags: civimail

I would like to update our logo in automatic email links to reflect the new brand.  I have not tried anything as I am new to the programme but would like some assistance here.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  This sounds like a good question, but you could make it better if you could provide some more detail.  In particular your version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. WordPress, Drupal or Joomla).

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to introduce an image or images into your message templates, which you can find under admin>mailings>message templates.

The documentation for this is at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/set-up/#creating-and-maintaining-message-templates